# i want to find a integer with a given pattern

Tags: c

I want to make a program that count numbers in a given range which have the given pattern in them to use only 'for' funtion, 'if~ else if' function, 'while' funtion, and function call.
get a start number ,end number and pattern number from user like this (10, 300, 11).
and the program will be count how many integers are like 11,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,211 that have 11 patter in them.

the range of each number is (1<=pattern, start, end number<=9999)

I tried to solve this problem with the classification of pattern that is one digit, two digit, three digit and four digit.(1<=pattern number<=9, 10<= pattern number<=99 like this.) but i don't know how to match each pattern digit to the ranged number.
below is my code please help me...
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

```
int nums, numf, nump;
int i=0;
int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0; 
int count=0;
printf("Start: ");
scanf("%d", &nums);
printf("End: ");
scanf("%d", &numf);
printf("Pattern: ");
scanf("%d", &nump);
if(1<=nump<10){
    for(i=nums; i<=numf; i++){
        a=i/1000;
        b=i/100%10;
        c=i/10%10;
        d=i%10;
        if(nump==d || nump==c || nump==b || nump==a ){
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("Result: %d", count);
}
else if(10<=nump<99){
    for(i=nums; i<=numf; i++){
        if(1<=i<10){
            continue;
        }
        else if(10<=i<99){
            if(i==nump){
                count++;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (100<=i<999){
            a=i/10;
            b=i%100;
            if(nump==a || nump==b){
                count++;
            }
        }
        else{
            a=i/100;
            b=i/10%100;
            c=i%100;
            if(nump==c || nump==b || nump==a ){
                count++;
            }
        }   
    }
    printf("Result: %d", count);
}
else if(100<=nump<999){
    for(i=nums; i<=numf; i++){
        if(i/10==0){
            continue;
        }
        else if(10<=i<99){
            continue;
        }
        else if (100<=i<999){
            if(i==nump){
                count++;
            }
        }
        else{
            a=i/10;
            b=i%1000;
            if( nump==b || nump==a ) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Result: %d", count);
}
else{
    for(i=nums; i<=numf; i++){
        if(nump==i){
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("Result: %d", count);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Can you some more code ? At least something you tried ?

Comment: hey i just add my code please check again!!

Comment: n ends with 11 is equivalent to n%100 == 11. n is like x11y : (n/10)%100 = 11…

Comment: what does it means? please tell me more concretely please...

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
start = 10
end = 300
pattern = 11
# find number of digits for pattern
tenFactor = 10
while pattern > tenFactor:
    tenFactor *= 10

found = []
# no number before pattern csn match pattern
num = max(start, pattern)
while num <= end:
    subnum = num
    # fin if last n digits of number == pattern
    # do this from num and by dividing num by 10 each tine
    while subnum >= pattern:
        if subnum % tenFactor == pattern:
            #print(num)
            found.append(num)
        subnum /= 10
    num += 1
print( found)
```

Output :

```
[11, 110, 111, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 211]
```

Comment: Note that it is not the only way to build the list. It could be done by constructing number by adding prefix and suffix to pattern